# Filling slot with a list of entities | Rasa

Tags: rasa

I am trying to get phone number form the user but sometimes the Speach recognition returns charachters instead of numbers, for instance:

"my contact is zero three one one seven two one one."

so to get these values i am using duckling with number dimenssion to detect this. it detects all the numbers as entities, so now what i need is to get all number values from the wntities and conactnate them to get full number and put it’s value in slot. I have tried using `self.from_entity('number')` but it only returns last value from the list.

is there any way to this, or any work around i should consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in a validation function by checking all values for the `number` entity extracted for a certain user message, and concatenating them. So you'd still fill your slot `from_entity` but in your validation function you'd actually go fetch all the values. There's an example for a similar thing for a sentence with dates/times, you'll need to follow the function definitions to see the details: https://github.com/RasaHQ/financial-demo/blob/d6f54f77b081b2136c892fce0fc2e999a2589616/actions/actions.py#L267

Answer (score 3):

My rasa version number is 1.9.6. I used [regular expression](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/entity-extraction/#regular-expressions-regex) to extract mobile no. We can reformat regex:mobileno based upon the requirements.

```
## intent:inform
- [97504*****](mobileno)
- [87459*****](mobileno)

## regex:mobileno
- [6789]{1}\d{4}?[\d]{5}$
```

rasa shell nlu output

```
Next Message: 
9999999999
{
  "intent": {
    "name": "inform",
    "confidence": 0.9978736042976379
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "mobileno",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 10,
      "extractor": "DIETClassifier",
      "value": "999999999"
    }
  ],
  ...,
  ...,
  "text": "9999999999"
}
```

Comment: in my case i am able to extract phone number using Duckling,
but at times my speech recognition returns me sentences without digits for which @Malinda has pointed us to right direction.